# How to update an element inside an array in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Right now this is the schema that I have

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const {Schema} = mongoose

const docsSchema = new Schema({
    github_id: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    folders: [{
        name: {
            type: String
        },
        docs: [{
            title: {
                type: String
            },
            body: {
                type: String
            }
        }]
    }]
},{timestamps: true})

const Docs = mongoose.model('Doc',docsSchema)

module.exports = Docs
```

what I want to do is create new docs inside specific folders. 
That means I have to update the `docs` array inside the `folders` array 
I am using mongoose, with express to create a rest API.

---

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to add multiple folders to a single Doc, you can use plain mongodb update syntax:

```
Docs.updateOne(
  { github_id: githubId, 'folders.folderName': folderName },
  { $push: { 'folders.$.docs': each: [newDocs] }
)
```

Note that this does not apply mongoose middlewares. If you need middlewares to run, use: `findOneAndUpdate`: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html

References:

- https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html#updating
- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/